# In 2020, are browserconfig.xml and ieconfig.xml now effectively deprecated?

Tags: internet-explorer

> *On August 17, 2020, Microsoft published a timeline indicating that Microsoft Teams will stop supporting Internet Explorer 11 on November
> 30, 2020 whereas Microsoft 365 products will end Internet Explorer 11
> support on August 17, 2021.*
>
> **Source:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11

I've searched **Webmasters SE** and the wider web but I can't find any current information.

I'm guessing (but haven't yet been able to confirm) that `ieconfig.xml` will now be deprecated on the same timeline as **Internet Explorer**. Will it?

Will `browserconfig.xml` also be deprecated? Or is the intention to use it for the foreseeable future?

If the latter, which browsers intend to keep using `browserconfig.xml`?

Just **MS Edge**? Or other browsers as well?

Comment: I thought it was Windows that used these files to show an icon on the desktop when somebody created a shortcut to your URL there.  I didn't think that IE used these files directly.

Comment: Even if it is only IE that uses these files, you may still need them until people stop using the browser.    It may take years for IE usage to dwindle out even after support stops.

Comment: Ah, is it a Windows file rather than an MSIE file? Thanks, @StephenOstermiller - I wasn't aware because I've never deployed `browserconfig.xml` (or `ieconfig.xml`). I'm working on a project now where I might need to (and if I need to, then I'm keen to, in order to learn about the format). Then, when I read the news about IE, I wondered if this whole approach to configuration was going to be deprecated. Do Chrome and Firefox etc. report the presence of `browserconfig.xml` to Windows then?

Comment: I don't think so.  It was my impression that Windows makes the requests itself.  Given the integration of the browser into the OS, the requests probably end up looking a lot like requests from IE.   I don't run Windows myself, so this is just based on reading I've done and not on any first hand experience.

Comment: Regarding your second point - I agree that's an absolutely valid approach, but I made a conscious decision to stop catering to IE users in 2010. Not because I'm against browser compatibility - on the contrary, I'm a strong advocate - but after writing standards compliant, universally cross-browser compatible sites from the early 2000s to 2010, I concluded that IE was so woefully lost that the time required to cater for its users wasn't justified. [1/2]

Comment: I likened IE users to black and white television owners who want to watch films in colour. The solution is to get a colour television. However, in this instance, while colour televisions can be expensive, Firefox, Opera, Chromium, Vivaldi etc. are free. [2/2]

Comment: That's very useful info on Windows 8 and Windows 10, @StephenOstermiller, thank you. (I'm still using Windows 7 - and very happy with it - so, even in 2020, I am unfamiliar with Metro / Tile Windows).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2021 here,

### Concerning deprecation

As long as there are people using agents that support this (i.e. mainly IE11), *Browser configuration* will remain semi-relevant, or at least usable. [Microsoft announced IE11 will go EOL on August 17th this year](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-365-apps-say-farewell-to-internet-explorer-11-and/ba-p/1591666), but we all know it will stick around here and there.

### Concerning the filename/URL

[The documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/dn320426(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) that you referred to in [your own answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/131437/82953), has the following code sample:

```
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="IEconfig.xml" />
```

I am assuming this is where the author of [the blog article you also refer to](https://www.viget.com/articles/tips-for-implementing-device-assets/) got the name `IEconfig.xml` from. *However*, the documentation then mentions:

> Note: If a webpage does not specify a browser configuration file, IE11 automatically looks for "browserconfig.xml" in the root directory of the server. To prevent this, use an "msapplication-config" header with the content attribute to "none" (shown earlier).

So, it appears the only reason they used `IEconfig.xml` in the example is that it’s not `browserconfig.xml` (in which case you wouldn’t need that metadata to begin with). This reminds me of their infamous `favicon.ico`, which you can also link to with markup, or just call the thing `favicon.ico` and be done with it.

### Concluding

I don’t see any negatives in supporting it (other than having to make the thing), and it might actually be useful to some users with agents that support it.

I would, however, strongly suggest always setting up a route for `/browserconfig.xml` if you decide to do so. That way, agents that support it will supposedly discover it automatically (which I generally think is bad UA practice, but there you have it), and you won’t have to pollute your markup with proprietary metadata that doesn’t mean anything to any other system.

(There might also be a minuscule performance benefit to having one, depending on how many IE11 visitors you have, and the way your server handles 404s and logging, but that’s probably more theoretical than anything.)

Comment: So what has replaced this if this has been deprecated?  Simple large favicon images?

Comment: @William, it’s not `browserconfig.xml` that is deprecated, but IE11, the only known (as far as I can tell) UA to support it. So, for other agents, nothing changes. They have their own methods of displaying icons, but that’s another question.

Comment: You might want to look into [Web App Manifest](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/), which is a similar concept, and has since been widely adopted by vendors.

Answer (score 6):

It's been a month since I asked this, so I thought I'd rummage around the internet some more and see what I could come up with.

---

### browserconfig.xml

According to this Microsoft Page:

- [Browser configuration schema reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/dn320426(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

This is an example of a `browserconfig.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
   <msapplication>
     <tile>
        <square70x70logo src="small.png"/>
        <square150x150logo src="medium.png"/>
        <wide310x150logo src="wide.png"/>
        <square310x310logo src="large.png"/>
        <TileColor>#009900</TileColor>
     </tile>
     <badge>
        <polling-uri src="badge.xml"/>
        <frequency>30</frequency>
     </badge>
     <notification>
        <polling-uri  src="1.xml"/>
        <polling-uri2 src="2.xml"/>
        <polling-uri3 src="3.xml"/>
        <polling-uri4 src="4.xml"/>
        <polling-uri5 src="5.xml"/>
        <frequency>30</frequency>
        <cycle>1</cycle>
     </notification>
   </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

---

### ieconfig.xml

According to this blog post:

- [Tips For Implementing Device Assets](https://www.viget.com/articles/tips-for-implementing-device-assets/)

This is an example of an `ieconfig.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <browserconfig>
    <msapplication>
      <tile>
        <square70x70logo src="ms-tile-128x128.png"/>
        <square150x150logo src="ms-tile-270x270.png"/>
        <wide310x150logo src="ms-tile-558x270.png"/>
        <square310x310logo src="ms-tile-558x558.png"/>
        <TileColor>#6a9a22</TileColor>
      </tile>
    </msapplication>
  </browserconfig>
```

That would seem to suggest that **browserconfig.xml** and **ieconfig.xml** are *different names for the same thing*... and there is some suggestion, though I can't confirm it, that the latter name, **ieconfig.xml**, is the current, correct name.

All that said, I still can't confirm if **Edge Browser** looks for, recognises or knows about **ieconfig.xml** so I can't answer the question and confirm if the latter is effectively deprecated or not.